# how to use in app navigation in windows 8.1 silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-8.1

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{

Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
if (frame == null)
{
    return;
}

if (frame.CanGoBack)
{
    frame.GoBack();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

}

while using this code in windows 8.1 silverlight i get error

Error   1   :The type or namespace name 'Frame' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   2   :The name 'Window' does not exist in the current context

plz help!
Thank you in adnvance

Comment: what do you want to do

Comment: What is your project type? Windows 8.1 Store App doesn't support silverlight. Windows Phone 8.1 support silverlight.

Comment: i want to navigate in app using the backpress button in windows 8.1 silverlight app for phone

Answer (score 0):

You app must not be silverlight to use in app navigation because ...

**windows.ui.xaml.controls** is not available for silverlight application....

Their are several namespaces deleted in 8.1 silverlight.... [You can check the deleted namespaces here](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/Windows%20Phone%208.1%20(Silverlight)-vs-Windows%20Phone%208.1.html)

Also winRt toolkit cant be used with silverlight at current situation....